# How to smooth the curve?

Tags: python, filter, fft, curve, smoothing

I am using the following code to draw a curve from my two column Raw data ( x=time , y=|float data|).The graph it is plotting is a rough edge graph. Is it possible to have a smooth edged on these data? I am attaching the code, data and curve.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
from matplotlib import style

# changing matplotlib the default style
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
#one of {'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w'}
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth']=1
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor']='.3'
plt.rcParams['xtick.color']='b'
plt.rcParams['ytick.color']='r'



x,y= np.loadtxt('MaxMin.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)
x = np.array([datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for i in x])
y = y.astype(float)

# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('<------Clock-Time(HH:MM:SS)------>') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/sq.sec)') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Sample graph!')
# plotting the points 
plt.plot(x, y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
#Custom Format
loc = matplotlib.dates.MicrosecondLocator(1000000)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

I have searched similar threads but the mathematical concepts used by them went over my head. So I cannot identify what exactly has to be done for my data.

[Generated Graph from RAW data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmWj9.jpg)

I am also giving the sample data file so that you can re-construct it at your end.

[Get Data File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADMgE_xjVHvt1DdnZNnt5Y-767DC-D6k/view?usp=sharing)

PS. I am also not being able to change the line color in the graph from default red even after using

```
plt.rcParams['lines.color']='g'
```

Although that is a minor issue in this case.

Comment: The data looks like it is non-chronological, so you get extra lines between points you probably do not want. Sort your input data chronological before plotting.

Comment: It is a time based chronologically sorted and cannot sort it otherwise. I was wondering if it can be smoothed using some kind of filter or a machine learning tool like SVM need to be applied. As these are the terminologies I am seeing around but have no idea what will be good for this data set.

Comment: What output are you expecting to see? The question is extremely broad as it stands, although the completeness of the example is very much commendable.

Answer (score 4):

The input data has wrong timestamps, the original author should have used zero-padding when formatting the milliseconds (`%03d`).

```
[...]
10:27:19.3 9.50560385141
10:27:19.32 9.48882194058
10:27:19.61 9.75936468731
10:27:19.91 9.96021690527
10:27:19.122 9.48972151383
10:27:19.151 9.49265161533
[...]
```

We need to fix that first:

```
x, y = np.loadtxt('MaxMin.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)

# fix the zero-padding issue
x_fixed = []
for xx in x:
    xs = xx.split(".")
    xs[1] = "0"*(3-len(xs[1])) + xs[1]
    x_fixed.append(xs[0] + '.' + xs[1])

x = np.array([datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for i in x_fixed])
y = y.astype(float)
```

You can then use a smoothing kernel (e.g. moving average) to smooth the data:

```
window_len = 3
kernel = np.ones(window_len, dtype=float)/window_len
y_smooth = np.convolve(y, kernel, 'same')
```

Comment: It's only useful to smooth the data if the data is actually properly monotonic.

Comment: It should be sorted already like that as the data is coming from sensors over a period of time. Have you checked the logic on the data file I shared? Kindly post the output graph to have me an idea, if that satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Well, it isn't.

Comment: The first column contain the timestamp in the format HH:MM:S.msec. And the data is sorted in ascending order of time.

Comment: See my comment in the answer. Whoever wrote the code which timestamped the data did it wrong. You can circumvent it, though.

Comment: i removed the sorting and added the workaround for the wrong timestamps, since this seems what is correct.

Comment: Actually I do not have any access on Data File generation. So has to work with whatever format I receive.

Comment: It fixes the issue, but this should really be reported to whoever is in charge of data acquisition.

Comment: Giving a syntax error at x = np.array([datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for i in x_fixed])

Comment: Yeah it is running now. The zero fix made it smooth. But there is no effect of adding the 'moving average' code [ Put it before last line plt.show()]. Will it fit somewhere else in the code? Forgive me for my ignorance.

Comment: Plot both `y` and `y_smooth` to see the difference. It's basically a low-pass filter.

Comment: Yeah, actually I never plotted y_smooth. Now the curve looks good. However the multiple maximas around the peak need to be converged into one [ all small peaks near highest peak should disappear]. Is it possible?

Comment: The y_smooth has altered the original maximum and minimum significantly [Decreased original maximum and increased original minimum]. Hence it cannot be used. Any work around with this? No problem when 'y' is plotted.

Comment: Well, the running average "gets rid" of short-time (high frequency) variations. Whether it is useful depends on what you want from the data. This is outside the scope of this post, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The `scipy` module has some ways of getting smooth curves through your points.  Try adding this to the top:

```
from scipy import interpolate
```

Then add these lines just before your `plt.show()`:

```
xnew = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100) 
bspline = interpolate.make_interp_spline(x, y)
y_smoothed = bspline(xnew)
plt.plot(xnew, y_smoothed)
```

If you do a little search for `scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline`, you can find more info on what that does.  But essentially, the combination of that and `np.linspace` generates a bunch of fake data points to make up a smooth curve.

Comment: I cannot add additional data for smoothing. However dropping portion of existing data is ok.